# Converting XAML Textbox to C# with Validation

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, textbox

I am trying to convert this xaml textbox with validation into C# so that it can be dynamically created and populated from code.  I am getting stuck creating the validation bindings.  Can anyone provide any hints?

```
<TextBox Height="20" Width="200" >
      <Binding RelativeSource="{x:Static RelativeSource.Self}" Path="Text" >
           <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <runtime:StandardTextBoxValidationRule/>
           </Binding.ValidationRules>
       </Binding>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Are you just dynamically creating the textbox from within the WPF page?

Comment: No it is being created in a control generating class that is with in the same assembly as the WPF page.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```
TextBox textBox = // Get or create the text box

var binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = RelativeSource.Self;
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Text");
binding.ValidationRules.Add(new StandardTextBoxValidationRule());
textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
```

Comment: I had to add the following to get it working

binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Text");

Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked.  I added that to my answer, as well, in case other poeple find this.

Comment: You can also use `new Binding("Text")`